# Jupyter Notebook issue in vscode (kernelspec module not installed in the selected interpreter)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

So, I was trying to use a jupyter notebook in VScode but it suddenly stopped working. I've verified my jupyter version:

```
jupyter core     : 4.7.0
jupyter-notebook : 6.1.5
qtconsole        : 4.7.7
ipython          : 7.19.0
ipykernel        : not installed
jupyter client   : not installed
jupyter lab      : not installed
nbconvert        : not installed
ipywidgets       : not installed
nbformat         : 5.0.8
traitlets        : 5.0.5
```

Alhto, when I try to install ipykernel or jupyter lab, my cmd returns that the requirements are already met. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataFox

There has been some issues with VSCode and Jupyter for me aswell recently. Normally these sorts of things you have to quit VSCode and restart it. If this doesn't work, you can try to copy and paste all your work/code into another `.ipynb` file. This worked for me.